# Can't get value params[:user] first request using mongrel_rails start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongrel

I get nil from params[:user] in create action of my controller for the first request when I start my mongrel server by using mongrel_rails start. After that for second and third time are ok. In addition, if I start my Mongrel by using script/server, it doesn't have any problems at all. It is different by starting mongrel server between script/server and mongrel_rails start? Have you ever faced this problem?

Here my code in controller:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = 'User was successfully created.'
      format.html { redirect_to(@user) }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user, :status => :created, :location => @user }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

And I use Poster add-on to test and post in xml format.

Comment: Would you like to paste your code so that users can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you want to check is the new action in your controller.
Second is the erb file which has your form. I have a feeling the text field tags are not proper.

I'd recommend inspecting the `params` object by:

```
logger.debug params.inspect # Will show up log/development.log
puts params.inspect # Will show up in server console
```

Comment: But I don't HTML form to post the data, I use Poster, a firefox addon for testing RESTful webservice, and put the data in message body directly.

Comment: Oops.. so you don't need to see the html form, but you would still need to inspect the `params` object